# Using a hash symbol in URL

Tags: angularjs, node.js, url, url-rewriting, hashtag

I have a web app where there exists hashtags.

My wish is to have a url like this: `www.example.com/tag/#hashtagname`

So that if the user wants to get more information about `#hashtagname` he can enter the URL simply like `www.example.com/tag/#hashtagname`

I know the hash symbol is used primarily as an anchor element in HTML pages, so does my wish to have the hashtag in the URL have any unwanted implications? I'm thinking SEO wise and if it's even technical possible?

I'm using AngularJS and running NodeJS and ExpressJS on the backend.

Comment: You can't do this.  The anchor tag part isn't even sent by the browser to the server.