# AJAX load animation for chat?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, chat

How do I add the slideDown jquery animation when I knew message is loaded? Perhaps I can't with my method for loading... A file takes user input and inserts into database. Another file pulls from database onto chatbox and styles.

Javascript Code:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form[name="chatbox"]');
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});

function submitChat() {
    if(chatbox.message.value == '') {
        alert('Error: Missing Fields.');
        return;
    }
    var message = chatbox.message.value;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==100) {
            document.getElementById('chatlog').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open('GET','chat.php?message='+message, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    chatbox.reset();
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    setInterval(function() {$('#chatlog').load('logs.php');}, 200);

});
```

Please let me know if you need the PHP attached.. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: # will link you to where you want to be on the page.

Comment: Can you please explain more

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807853/using-a-hash-symbol-in-url